# JPA / Hibernate ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, jpa

I've just migrated a spring MVC (**3.2.8**) app from Ant to Maven, so I haven't changed the code, only the libraries, because of the dependencies imported automatically.
Since then I have a lot of DB errors, 
like ORA-00932, trnasactions time outs.....

or for instance this one:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:310)
       at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3275)
       at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3067)
       at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
       at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:688)
       at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:544)
       at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:281)
       at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:229)
       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:228)
       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
       at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
       at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
       at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
       at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
       at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:93)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.createQuery(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.createQuery(Unknown Source)
       at eu.europa.ec.env.ecolabel.dao.impl.ApplicationDaoImpl.findByFirstSignatory(ApplicationDaoImpl.java:110)
       at eu.europa.ec.env.ecolabel.services.impl.LicenseServiceImpl.getApplications(LicenseServiceImpl.java:417)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.getApplications(Unknown Source)
```

or this:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:637)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:307)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy259.flush(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy259.flush(Unknown Source)
```

The DB is:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

Here the hibertante jars imported...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moved all the persistence annotations like this from the method getProperty to the property itself solved the problem

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    @JoinColumn(name = "THIRD_SIGNATORY", unique = true, nullable = true)
```